# Having problems when returning a variable using jquery

Tags: jquery, return

I dont know why this code doesnt work :S

```
function check(){
  var haySaldo=false;
  $.post("controlarSaldo.php", function(data)

 {  
        if(data>0)
          haySaldo=true;
  });

   return haySaldo;
}
```

Information:

data=1000

I put an alert of haySaldo inside jquery and I get "true" but outside jquery I get "false" :S

Many thx in advance!

Comment: You might want to try `data.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `return` statement is outside your function.

Try this

```
$.post("controlarSaldo.php", function(data){   
    var haySaldo=false;    
    if(data>0){
        haySaldo=true;
    }
    return haySaldo;
});
```

Comment: I tried that before but it seems that it doesnt return the value of the variable properly

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if you already understand this, but this jQuery post method is a shorthand for an AJAX requests, which means that your code will not wait for the AJAX request to complete before returning the value of haySaldo (as you have it written).

It's a little unclear what you are intending to do by calling return from inside the success method. Perhaps if you provided a little more information people could offer better suggestions.

One thing you may want to check out are jQuery's [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). It would allow you to do something like this.

```
function check(){
  return $.post("controlarSaldo.php").success(function(data)
    {  
    if(data>0)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
    });
}
```

Then later on in your code you can do (untested).

```
check().done(function(resp){ 
  if(resp){
    // Do true thing
  }
  else{
    // Do false thing
  }
});
```

Comment: I wanna return true if data>0 and false if it is <0
Then I call the function check() and if check()==true I do something, and if it is false another thing, but even If data > 0 I always get false and I dont know why.

Comment: Ah, yes, since check() is an ajax call you can't simply do check()==true, since the execution will not wait around for check() to finish the request.

Comment: I tried with check().done(function(resp) but it doesn't do anything, I mean, I put some code inside the if and inside the else but it seems it doesn't reach there :S